# Jenkins Next Generation Warning Plugin Checkstyle throw an error

Tags: jenkins, checkstyle

i stumble upon error when using jenkins next generation warning plugin with checkstyle setup.

the config i taken from [github](https://github.com/checkstyle/checkstyle/blob/master/src/main/resources/google_checks.xml) link. i dont know what steps that i should take next to reconfigure my checkstyle plugin.

here is the screenshot

[image]

Comment: The error isn't coming from checkstyle so you will have to do some more analysis. What version of checkstyle is in jenkins? Can you use the config directly with the same checkstyle CLI without issue? The link you provided for the config is checkstyle master, which can have breaking changes with older versions of checkstyle.

Answer (score 0):

Warnings-ng plugin needs a checkstyle **report**, not the original checkstyle config.
It looks like your configuration is wrong and you are trying to feed the config to plugin.
Checkstyle report is located (for maven build) in `target/checkstyle-result.xml` and looks like (in this case no violations)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<checkstyle version="8.31">
</checkstyle>
```